# Connection via Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy Failed

Tags: google-cloud-platform

[image]I am getting the following disconnection issues in the GCP Jupiter notebook.

error code: 4010
and
error code: 1006

Can you please suggest some solution?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As part of the IAP configuration steps, you should create a [firewall rule](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding#create-firewall-rule) that allows ingress traffic to the SSH port from the IAP address range:

```
GCP Console => VPC network => Firewall rules => Create Firewall Rule
  Name:     allow-ingress-from-iap
  Direction of traffic:     Ingress
  Target:   All instances in the network 
  Source filter:    IP ranges 
  Source IP ranges:     35.235.240.0/20 
  Protocols and ports:  select TCP and enter 22 to allow SSH
```

[Identity-Aware Proxy > Doc > Setting up IAP for Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/tutorial-gce)

The error 1006 appears in the GCP Console UI after 1 hour of inactivity of the SSH session via IAP with VMs with Internal IP only, and this is a session timeout on the Google side.

Comment: Does this solution also work for 
Error code:1006 ?

Comment: As far as I know the error 1006 appears in the GCP Console UI after 1 hour of inactivity of the SSH session via IAP with VMs with Internal IP only, and this is a session timeout on the Google side.

Comment: Thanks, @mebius99 You are like god to me

Comment: @SahilKamboj: resolved error 1006 for me, yes.

Answer (score 5):

As @mebius99 has mentioned, IAP (Identity-Aware Proxy) requests come from the IP address range `35.235.240.0/20`.

Your network firewall must allow these requests to be able to SSH through IAP.

One way to do that (create a firewall-rule) is to run `gcloud compute firewall-rules create` command.

To do that, first open the cloud shell on the Google cloud console,
[image]

Then once the cloud shell opens up, run the following:

`gcloud compute firewall-rules create ssh-ingress-from-iap --allow=tcp:22 --source-ranges 35.235.240.0/20 --network [network-name]`

Replace `[network-name]` with your network name (the default VPC network is named: `default`)

If the above solution doesn't work (or have a similar firewall rule in place already), consider checking the network tags (on the firewall-rules and the VM). It maybe the case that your firewall-rule is allowing the requests to only certain instances that has some tags and the instance you're trying to SSH into doesn't.

Comment: Does this solution also work for 
Error code:1006 ?

Comment: @SahilKamboj it did for me! thank you for this solution! Worked like a charm for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me the error 1006 was related to system Time. I had changed the system time manually to another time zone. SSH worked when system time was sy

Answer (score 0):

Create a firewall for port 22 and add this IP `35.235.240.0/20`
attach it to all VM so you will able to establish connection