# Google Cloud Platform SSH error code 1006

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, google-compute-engine

I made an instance and connected SSH in my project. My project is for machine learning, so I opened jupyter notebook and ran it. But the terminal always sends me an error like this.
"Connection via Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy Failed
Code: 1006
Please ensure you can make a proper https connection to the IAP for TCP hostname:https://tunnel.cloudproxy.app.
You may be able to connect without using the Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy."

I have tried to create firewall rule but this doesn't work.
Someone says that this is because of session timeout. If it is, what can I do to solve it?

Comment: How did you set up your firewall? Do you have allowed ingress traffic from IP range 35.235.240.0/20 for IAP and allow your IP? You can follow up this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63151385/12260268)

Comment: Code 1006 is that your session is timing out. To keep your session active, you need to be active in the session. If you are not using the service, you will be disconnected.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63147497/connection-via-cloud-identity-aware-proxy-failed